# SQL info shown in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

```
SELECT CA.MEMBER_ID,
    0 AS TRANSFERRED_SHARES ,
    SUM(CA.NUMBER_OF_SHARES) AS PURCHASED_SHARES, 
    '-' AS DELETED_SHARES
FROM COS_APPLICATIONS CA , COS_APPL_DETAILS CAD
WHERE APPL_TYPE =2
    AND CA.APPLICATION_ID = CAD.APPLICATION_ID
    AND CA.SERVICE_PRODUCT = 38002
    AND CAD.TRX_TYPE = 'INITIAL'
    AND CAD.TRX_UNIT = 143
    GROUP BY CA.MEMBER_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT CA.MEMBER_ID,
    SUM(CA.NUMBER_OF_SHARES) AS TRANSFERRED_SHARES, 
    0 AS PURCHASED_SHARES ,
    '-' AS DELETED_SHARES
FROM COS_APPLICATIONS CA , COS_APPL_DETAILS CAD
WHERE APPL_TYPE =5
   AND CA.APPLICATION_ID = CAD.APPLICATION_ID
   AND CA.SERVICE_PRODUCT = 38002
   AND CAD.TRX_TYPE = 'INITIAL'
   AND CAD.TRX_UNIT = 143 
   GROUP BY CA.MEMBER_ID
   ORDER BY CA.MEMBER_ID
```

I get the following results:

My issue is that when a Member has both transferred and purchased shares,i want the info in one row , and not seperately.
E.g. a member with the ID 63, has 31 Tranferred Shares and 50 Purchased.My query gives me 2 rows : the first one has 0 for the transferred and 50 for the purchased, and the second one has 31 for the transferred and 0 for the purchased. All i want is this info is shown in one row.

Unfortunately i can't attach any image yet.

Note! I execute this query in SQL Server 2012.

Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said in my comment, stop using implicit joins. it's not 1989 anymore: 
[Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

No need for 2 different `SELECT` statements here. Use a proper `JOIN` and `IN` to return the data, and a simple `CASE` expression within your `SUM`:

```
SELECT CA.MEMBER_ID,
       SUM(CASE APPL_TYPE WHEN 5 THEN CA.NUMBER_OF_SHARES END) AS TRANSFERRED_SHARES, --APPL_TYPE is missing table alias
       SUM(CASE APPL_TYPE WHEN 2 THEN CA.NUMBER_OF_SHARES END) AS PURCHASED_SHARES, --APPL_TYPE is missing table alias
       '-' AS DELETED_SHARES
FROM COS_APPLICATIONS CA
     JOIN COS_APPL_DETAILS CAD ON CA.APPLICATION_ID = CAD.APPLICATION_ID
WHERE APPL_TYPE IN (2, 5) --APPL_TYPE is missing table alias
  AND CA.SERVICE_PRODUCT = 38002
  AND CAD.TRX_TYPE = 'INITIAL'
  AND CAD.TRX_UNIT = 143
GROUP BY CA.MEMBER_ID
ORDER BY CA.MEMBER_ID;
```

Comment: Worked fine. Thank you for the tips!

Comment: @MiltosDimitriadis you're welcome. Please do stop ticking and unticking the solution button though! (Too many notifications)

Comment: I need your help again! I'm desperate! I can't attach any image yet and it's quite difficult to describe my problem without one. Can you help me??

Comment: If you can't describe your problem, that's going to make it impossible to help you on, however, you should be asking a new question, not commenting on an old one.

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation on one level top

```
select MEMBER_ID,sum(TRANSFERRED_SHARES) as TRANSFERRED_SHARES ,sum(PURCHASED_SHARES) as URCHASED_SHARES
from 
(SELECT CA.MEMBER_ID,
    0 AS TRANSFERRED_SHARES ,
    SUM(CA.NUMBER_OF_SHARES) AS PURCHASED_SHARES, 
    '-' AS DELETED_SHARES
FROM COS_APPLICATIONS CA , COS_APPL_DETAILS CAD
WHERE APPL_TYPE =2
    AND CA.APPLICATION_ID = CAD.APPLICATION_ID
    AND CA.SERVICE_PRODUCT = 38002
    AND CAD.TRX_TYPE = 'INITIAL'
    AND CAD.TRX_UNIT = 143
    GROUP BY CA.MEMBER_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT CA.MEMBER_ID,
    SUM(CA.NUMBER_OF_SHARES) AS TRANSFERRED_SHARES, 
    0 AS PURCHASED_SHARES ,
    '-' AS DELETED_SHARES
FROM COS_APPLICATIONS CA , COS_APPL_DETAILS CAD
WHERE APPL_TYPE =5
   AND CA.APPLICATION_ID = CAD.APPLICATION_ID
   AND CA.SERVICE_PRODUCT = 38002
   AND CAD.TRX_TYPE = 'INITIAL'
   AND CAD.TRX_UNIT = 143 
   GROUP BY CA.MEMBER_ID
)X GROUP BY MEMBER_ID
```

OR use conditional aggregation

```
SELECT CA.MEMBER_ID,
        SUM(case when APPL_TYPE =5 then CA.NUMBER_OF_SHARES end) AS TRANSFERRED_SHARES ,
        SUM(case when APPL_TYPE =2 then CA.NUMBER_OF_SHARES end) AS PURCHASED_SHARES, 
        '-' AS DELETED_SHARES
    FROM COS_APPLICATIONS CA inner join COS_APPL_DETAILS CAD
    on CA.APPLICATION_ID = CAD.APPLICATION_ID
    where 
        CA.SERVICE_PRODUCT = 38002
        and CAD.TRX_TYPE = 'INITIAL'
        AND CAD.TRX_UNIT = 143
        GROUP BY CA.MEMBER_ID
```

Comment: @MiltosDimitriadis if you are using a solution here, I strongly suggest the second (which is basically identical to mine). The first is not the right choice here. Note, also, however, that the second answer will produce rows for `COS_APPLICATIONS` that do not have a value of `5` or `2` for `APPL_TYPE`. mine will not.